# SUM() and group by with sub same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've this data in my table

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| master-milk | 100 |
| submaster-milk | 200 |
| master-coffee | 10 |
| submaster-coffee | 20 |

And I need to calculate SUM() of my milk and coffee
Sum(milk) = 300 and sum(coffee) = 30

```
Select col1,sum(col1) as total from Table  
group by col1
```

Comment: Poor table design, put master in one column and milk in another, and this will become much easier.

Comment: Delimited data is not atomic (obviously) and fundamentally breaks first-normal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) to first categorize the rows and then perform the SUM operation.

```
;WITH CTEData AS (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN Col1 LIKE '%milk' THEN 'milk'
            WHEN Col1 LIKE '%coffee' THEN 'coffee'
            ELSE 'other'
        END AS DrinkType,
        Col2
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT DrinkType, SUM(Col2) AS Total
FROM CTEData GROUP BY DrinkType;
```

Comment: chocolate milk, banana milk...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING` to extract milk/coffee from the string :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1, CHARINDEX('-', Col1)+1, LEN(Col1)) as Col1, sum(Col2) as Total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Col1, CHARINDEX('-', Col1)+1, LEN(Col1))
```

Comment: I *hope* the OP doesn't have something with a 3 part name. (`'master-coffee-milk'`).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Col1 LIKE '%milk' THEN 'milk'
        WHEN Col1 LIKE '%coffee' THEN 'coffee'
        ELSE 'other'
    END AS DrinkType,
    SUM(Col2) AS Total
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY  CASE 
        WHEN Col1 LIKE '%milk' THEN 'milk'
        WHEN Col1 LIKE '%coffee' THEN 'coffee'
        ELSE 'other'
    END
```